# Apply filter over entire project, with a separate div

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to make an overlay class. My dom element tree would look as follows:

```
<body>
  <div id="root">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="gaussian-blur"></div>
    <div class="modal"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

`#root` is where my application will be rendered. `.overlay` will be conditionally added to the dom on a click event. I want `.overlay > .gaussian-blur` to apply a mask over the entire application, not including `.overlay > .modal`.

My `.gaussian-blur` CSS looks as follows:

```
.overlay > .gaussian-blur {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  filter: blur(6px);
  transition: filter 200ms ease-in-out;
}
```

However, this does not seem to blur out the `#root` component as if it were an overlay.

I can add styles directly to the root component which will apply the blur, but not on div that overlays it.

Is there any way to do this with CSS?

Comment: No, you can not blur elements that are outside of the element you apply the filter to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sibblings and javascript or an input element ahead in the flow.

You only have to blur the root element itself when needed (using CSS or javascript).

Here is an easy CSS/HTML example with `input` + `label` to toggle modal element  and blur root

```css
input#modal ~ .overlay {
  display:none;
}
.overlay {
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  position:fixed;  
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
input#modal:checked ~ .overlay {
  display:flex;
}
input#modal:checked ~ #root {
  filter:blur(3px);
}
.modal {
  background:white;
  border:solid;
  padding:1em;
  max-width:75%;
}
#modal {
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
}
[for="modal"] {
  border:solid;
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:blue;
  padding:0.25em;
  background:lightgray;
}

#root {
background:url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature/1);
background-size:cover
}
```

```html
<!-- demo purpoe but usable for nowdays browsers -->
<input type="checkbox" id="modal"/>

<div id="root">
  <label for="modal">Show modal </label>
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="modal">
  <label for="modal">Hide modal </label>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```